# RestKit 0.20.1 Composite keys and nested relationships

Tags: ios, xml, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I am using RestKit 0.20.1 to map an XML feed to a Core Data Model. These are as follows:

### XML Feed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<payload>
    <competitions>
        <competition id="100" name="Comp A" />
        <competition id="200" name="Comp B" />
        <competition id="300" name="Comp C" />
        <competition id="400" name="Comp D" />
    </competitions>
    <seasons>
        <season id="10" span="2008/09"/>
        <season id="20" span="2009/10"/>
        <season id="30" span="2010/11"/>
        <season id="40" span="2011/12"/>
        <season id="50" span="2012/13"/>
    </seasons>
    <players>
        <player id="1" name="Justyn Spooner">
            <season id="10">
                <playerstats competitionID="100" goals="0" played="0" />
                <playerstats competitionID="200" goals="5" played="4" />
                <playerstats competitionID="300" goals="2" played="1" />
            </season>
            <season id="20">
                <playerstats competitionID="300" goals="1" played="4" />
                <playerstats competitionID="400" goals="2" played="9" />
            </season>
        </player>
    </players>
</payload>
```

### Core Data Model

[image: Core Data Model]

So far I have the entity mappings setup and the response descriptors configured but am not sure how to setup the relationships between them.

### Entity Mapping

```
RKEntityMapping *playerMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Player" inManagedObjectStore:[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] managedObjectStore]];
playerMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"attID"];
[playerMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
    @"id"   : @"attID",
    @"name" : @"attName"
}];

RKEntityMapping *competitionMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Competition" inManagedObjectStore:[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] managedObjectStore]];
competitionMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"attID"];
[competitionMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
    @"id"   : @"attID",
    @"name" : @"attName"
}];

RKEntityMapping *seasonMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Season" inManagedObjectStore:[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] managedObjectStore]];
seasonMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"attID"];
[seasonMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
    @"id"   : @"attID",
    @"span" : @"attYearSpan"
}];

RKEntityMapping *playerStatsMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"PlayerStats" inManagedObjectStore:[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] managedObjectStore]];
playerStatsMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"attFKCompetitionID", @"attFKSeasonID", @"attFKPlayerID"];
[playerStatsMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
    @"competitionID" : @"attFKCompetitionID",
    @"????"          : @"attFKSeasonID",
    @"????"          : @"attFKPlayerID",
    @"goals"         : @"attGoals",
    @"played"        : @"attGamesPlayed"
}];
```

Response Descriptors

```
RKResponseDescriptor *playerResponseDescriptor =        [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:playerMapping       pathPattern:kURLBasePath@"/players" keyPath:@"payload.players.player"                       statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
RKResponseDescriptor *seasonResponseDescriptor =        [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:seasonMapping       pathPattern:kURLBasePath@"/players" keyPath:@"payload.seasons.season"                       statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
RKResponseDescriptor *competitionResponseDescriptor =   [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:competitionMapping  pathPattern:kURLBasePath@"/players" keyPath:@"payload.competitions.competition"             statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
RKResponseDescriptor *playerStatsResponseDescriptor =   [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:playerStatsMapping  pathPattern:kURLBasePath@"/players" keyPath:@"payload.players.player.season.playerstats"    statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

Aside from the missing relationships, you'll notice that in the playerStatsMapping I need to add an identificationAttribute that is made up of the three primary keys of Player, Season and Competition. The competition id is easily mapped as it is directly under the keyPath `payload.players.player.season.playerstats` (defined in the `playerStatsResponseDescriptor`). The problem is that I don't know how to reference the `parent.id` and `parent.parent.id` from the `playerStatMapping` to map to the attFKSeasonID and attFKPlayerID respectively.

I don't think RestKit support accessing a parent keyPath in the entityMappings and I'm sure there is probably another way around this? This diagram show what I want to pull out:

[image: XML Mapping]

In pseudo code, this is what I would be wanting to do if I wasn't using RestKit:

```
For each player in the XML response:
{
    find out if that player exists in Core Data; create if not
    keep it around in a local variable
    for each season under the player in the XML:
    {
        create if needed; keep around.
        for each competition under the season in the XML:
        {
            create if needed; keep around.
            Take the current player, season and competition. 
            Is there a PlayerStat matching those three things? Create if not
            Set that player stat's attGoals and attGamesPlayed to the values that are mapped from goals and played in the XML
        }
    }
}
```

So there are essentially two questions here:

1. How would you setup the relationship mappings?
2. How would you map the `player` and `season` ids when constructing the `playerStatsMapping` so that the `playerStatsMapping` can use them as the `identificationAttributes`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Justyn

Comment: Do you really need the ids once you have the relationships? Using the relationships you can navigate to the stats or predicate searches on the relationship destination objects. Will that work for you?

Comment: @Wain Thanks for the quick response. The relationships may solve it. I've updated the question to make it clearer. I currently don't have any way to identify an individual `playerstat` as it doesn't have its own ID. I was hoping to generate this from the competition it references and its parents (Player and Season). These three combined keys should allow to create a unique key for the playerStats entry. I'm doing this as I thought RestKit required a mapping to have an identificationAttribute set in order for it to be able to detect and update an existing entry rather than creating a new one?

Comment: True, the identificationAttribute is important. The best option for the identity may be to implement 'willSave' in the managed object subclass and generate the value there by interrogating the relationships. I don't think there is a way to back navigate during mapping. Possibly by trying to edit the mapping variables during the mapping process (I haven't tried that before).

Comment: OK, I'll continue to play with it and post back if I find out how to do this. The 'willSave' option could be a good fall back if nothing else works. Thanks.

Comment: I probably should have split this up into seperate questions, but how would you create the relationships for this mapping?

Comment: I guess you'll run into a similar problem because the relationship setup would use foreign keys and you only have direct access to one of them. I'm wondering if @metadata can help, but it looks like not yet: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/1327

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, RestKit now supports the `@parent` and `@root` mapping keys as part of the [development branch](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/1327#ref-pullrequest-15281421). This allows access to the parent nodes of the currently mapped object IF it is being mapped as a relationship of its parent entity.

This is very similar to another issue I had, I can provide an answer to the specific case above in more detail if required, otherwise please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16957907/1130260).