# Restkit use @parent in nested Foreign Key relationship

Tags: ios, json, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm having the hardest time setting up some relationships using RestKit.

There is a one-to-many relationship from `item` to `venue`, but through multiple levels of relationshups.

Here's an outline of the JSON structure:

```
{
    "id": 1, 
    "name": "Venue Name", 
    "sections": [
        {
            "id": 1, 
            "name": "Paper", 
            "categories": [
                {
                    "id": 1, 
                    "name": "Paper Goods", 
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "venue" : 1
                            // Other data goes here
                        }
                }
         }
}
```

I am trying to connect the `venue` foreign key to the `id` attribute of `Venue`.

I have tried doing the following:

```
NSEntityDescription * itemEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"DSItem" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext];
NSRelationshipDescription * venueRel = [itemEntity relationshipsByName][@"venue"];
RKConnectionDescription * connection = [[RKConnectionDescription alloc] initWithRelationship:venueRel attributes:@{@"venue" : @"pk"}]; // id --> pk on DSVenue class
```

But it the venue attribute is nil after the object mapping.

How can I use `@parent` in this to create the foreign key relationship? Or is there a better way?

Something like:

```
@{@"@parent.@parent.@parent.pk" : @"venue"}
```

I have looked that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918002/restkit-0-20-1-how-to-map-parent-id) SO question but it seems to apply to linking attributes to parent attributes, rather than linking foreign keys to entities.

Any help will be appreciated!

Edit: Here's all the mapping code

```
RKEntityMapping *itemMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"DSItem" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
itemMapping.identificationAttributes = [DSItem identificationAttributes];
[itemMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:[DSItem attributeMappings]];

NSEntityDescription * itemEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"DSItem" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext];
NSRelationshipDescription * venueRel = [itemEntity relationshipsByName][@"venue"];
RKConnectionDescription * connection = [[RKConnectionDescription alloc] initWithRelationship:venueRel keyPath:@"venue"];

[itemMapping addConnection:connection];

RKEntityMapping *categoryMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"DSCategory" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
categoryMapping.identificationAttributes = [DSCategory identificationAttributes];
[categoryMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:[DSCategory attributeMappings]];
[categoryMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"items" mapping:itemMapping];

RKEntityMapping *sectionMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"DSSection" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
sectionMapping.identificationAttributes = [DSSection identificationAttributes];
[sectionMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:[DSSection attributeMappings]];
[sectionMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"categories" mapping:categoryMapping];

RKEntityMapping *venueMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"DSVenue" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[venueMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:[DSVenue attributeMappings]];
venueMapping.identificationAttributes = [DSVenue identificationAttributes];
[venueMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"sections" mapping:sectionMapping];

RKResponseDescriptor *venueDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:venueMapping
                                                                                     method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                                pathPattern:[DSVenue pathPattern]
                                                                                    keyPath:[DSVenue keyPath]
                                                                                statusCodes:successIndexSet];


RKResponseDescriptor *itemDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:itemMapping
                                                                                    method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                               pathPattern:[DSItem pathPattern]
                                                                                   keyPath:[DSItem keyPath]
                                                                               statusCodes:successIndexSet];

[manager addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:@[itemDescriptor, venueDescriptor]];
```

Comment: Your JSON is nested so why are you trying to use foreign key mapping? You should just link the mappings direct with relationships.

Comment: I need to be able to sort the items by venue, basically. How can I link a 3-level-deep relationship to the top-most entity?

Comment: You don't have all the relationships linked to the top mapping, they are created at each level. Show the entities in the model you're mapping into.

Comment: I added all of the code for the mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't do what you're trying to do. Your mappings look fine and, assuming you have the inverse relationships configured in the model, you can just navigate the relationships from the item entity to get to the associated venue entity.

That said, I think the `@parent.id` reference should work to make the connection possible (by giving access to the id). But again, really not required. You can fetch and predicate on the model to get whatever information you need with the relationships you have.

Comment: I was trying to avoid the possible performance issues of spanning multiple relationships in a predicate, but I think you're right. I'll do it that way.